# Syntax of Declaring a Constructor in Header (.h) and then Defining in a Class File (.cpp) C++

Tags: c++, constructor

If anyone could lay this out, I would appreciate it.
Example of what I thought would work (assume the needed #include statements are there):

```
//.h file
class someclass(){}

//.cpp
someclass::
    someclass(){
         //implementation
         // of 
         //class
};
```

Comment: Since when do classes have parentheses before the braces?

Comment: @chris: It looks like the OP meant that as the constructor declaration...

Comment: @BillyONeal Correct. What I am most confused about is that I have a constructor with multiple parameters that works fine.

Comment: @BillyONeal, Oh, the `class` part threw me off guard.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

someclass.h file

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H
#define SOME_CLASS_H    

class someclass
{
public:
  someclass();  // declare default constructor

private:
  int member1; 
};

#endif
```

someclass.cpp

```
someclass::someclass()   // define default constructor
: member1(0)             // initialize class member in member initializers list
{
   //implementation
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Header:

```
//.h file
class someclass
{
    someclass();
}; // <-- don't forget semicolon here
```

Source:

```
#include "someClass.h"
//.cpp
someclass::someclass()
{
    // Implementation goes here
} // <-- No semicolon here
```

Comment: wouldn't this be `#include "someclass.h` [ without the capital C ]

Answer (score 5):

You have to *declare* the constructor in your class if you want to provide a *definition* for it. You are only doing the second thing.

Also, your original class definition contains some mistakes: no parentheses are needed after the class name, and a semicolon is needed after the final curly brace.

```
class someclass
{
    someClass(); // Here you DECLARE your constructor
};

...

someclass::someclass() // Here you DEFINE your constructor
{
    ...
}
```