# sclite (SCTK), C++ template argument, Filter::Filter* , is invalid. Cygwin

Tags: c++, c, templates, makefile, header-files

#### Problem

I am currently trying to install NIST's `sclite`, which is part of SCTK 2.4.0 ([github](https://github.com/chinshr/sctk) or [newer version](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools)). I am attempting the install on `Cygwin` in `bash`. The installation is done using `make`.

I was able to get past an issue with `file [format] not recognized` by doing a 64-bit compilation, as described at the end of the [README](https://github.com/chinshr/sctk/blob/master/README) and as explained in detail in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278663/6505499) of my SO posts.

Now, I again follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/chinshr/sctk/blob/master/INSTALL) and get the following error after typing `make all`

```
In file included from main.cpp:20:0:
recording.h:122:36: error: template argument 2 is invalid
         map<string, Filter::Filter*> filters;
                                    ^
recording.h:122:36: error: template argument 4 is invalid
make[3]: *** [makefile:59: main.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory 
'/cygdrive/c/Me/programs/nist/sctk/src/asclite/core'
make[2]: *** [makefile:12: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory 
'/cygdrive/c/Me/programs/nist/sctk/src/asclite'
make[1]: *** [makefile:12: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Me/programs/nist/sctk/src'
make: *** [makefile:20: all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what I can do to complete the install?

**Note**: When the question here is answered, the install doesn't actually complete on Cygwin. There are things to do [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278663/6505499) and [after](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283077/6505499), which I'm posting on SO with my progress and with questions on where to go next.

---

#### My Attempts

I haven't found anything about `Filter` in C++ docs, and a search through the files in the cloned directory ( `$ find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -print0 | xargs -I'{}' -0 grep -Hn "Filter" {}` ) gives, in part:

```
./src/asclite/core/checker.h:26:class Checker : public Filter
./src/asclite/core/filter.cpp:19: * Abstract interface to a Filter.
./src/asclite/core/filter.cpp:25:Filter::Filter()
./src/asclite/core/filter.cpp:30:Filter::~Filter()
./src/asclite/core/filter.h:26: * Abstract interface to a Filter.
./src/asclite/core/filter.h:28:class Filter
./src/asclite/core/filter.h:32:         Filter();
./src/asclite/core/filter.h:34:         virtual ~Filter();

...
```

Which, as far as I can tell, means that there is a constructor, `Filter` in the namespace, `Filter`.

Here's the "code part" of `filter.cpp`

```
$ cat src/asclite/core/filter.cpp | tail -16

/**
 * Abstract interface to a Filter.
 */

#include "filter.h" // class's header file

// class constructor
Filter::Filter()
{
}

// class destructor
Filter::~Filter()
{
}
```

Here's the code part for `filter.h`

```
$ cat src/asclite/core/filter.h | tail -27

#ifndef FILTER_H
#define FILTER_H

#include "stdinc.h"
#include "speech.h"
#include "speechset.h"

/**
 * Abstract interface to a Filter.
 */
class Filter
{
        public:
                // class constructor
                Filter();
                // class destructor
                virtual ~Filter();

                virtual bool isProcessAllSpeechSet() = 0;
                virtual unsigned long int ProcessSingleSpeech(Speech* speech) = 0;
                virtual unsigned long int ProcessSpeechSet(SpeechSet* ref, map<string, SpeechSet*> &hyp) = 0;

                virtual void LoadFile(const string& filename) = 0;
};

#endif // FILTER_H
```

---

#### System Details

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 CAP-D-ENG-INT3 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) 2018-02-02 15:16 x86_64 Cygwin
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) ...
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.4.0 ...
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.4.0 ...
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin ...
$ systeminfo | sed -n 's/^OS\ *//p'
Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
Configuration:          Member Workstation
Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

Comment: There is a way that I think is easier. Basically, you install the `tools` part of [kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org/). You can also install the `src` part and use it if you want (unless you're on Cygwin under Windows 7 as I am, in which case there are more problems.) If you just want the `sclite` stuff, copy `/path/to/kaldi/tools/sctk-2.4.10/*` to a place that's not inside the kaldi tree. I did `mkdir $HOME/sctk-2.4.10 && cp /path/to/kaldi/tools/sctk-2.4.10/* $HOME/sctk2.4.10/` . I'll probably elaborate later. Then you can `rm -rf /path/to/kaldi` .

Comment: Note that the fixes described here and in the other solutions to which I've linked ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278663/6505499), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283077/6505499)) are also needed if one uses a more current version of `sclite` available at jaguar.ncsl.nist.gov/pub/sctk-2.4.10-20151007-1312Z.tar.bz2

Comment: That more-current-version link might change, so here's the hosting site: [https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### <s>The</s> My Answer

(Also look at my comment under the question, describing the `kaldi` solution.)

**Note**: There was another problem which came up after this problem was solved. See the bottom of this answer for help with that.

I kept working on this, and I found the answer ended up being changing the line in question (and some others) as I will show. As a reminder, the line in question was from the file, `src/asclite/core/recording.h`

```
recording.h:122:28: error: template argument 2 is invalid
         map<string, Filter::Filter*> filters;
```

I changed it to

```
map<string, ::Filter*> filters;
```

I also made the same change ( `Filter::Filter*` to `::Filter*` ) in `src/asclite/core/recording.cpp`, lines 157 and 164, the results being:

```
157: map<string, ::Filter*>::iterator fi, fe;

164: ::Filter* ptr_elt = fi->second;
```

In looking for the answer and an explanation, I also found [another page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410542/problem-installing-sctk-2-4-0-on-ubuntu-13-10) that has the solution, but no explanation.

There is a "Let me clarify" note in the explanation below that expounds on the fact that this is only a partial solution to the install.

---

#### Research and (Hopefully) Explanation

I first noticed that the declarations before and after the line in question had no namespace and double colon, whereas our line had `Filter::Filter*`, as can be seen below:

$ cat src/asclite/core/recording.h | head -n 130 | tail -24
        map aligner;

```
        /**
         * contain all the available Scorer
         */
        map<string, Scorer*> scorer;

        /**
         * contain all the available Segmentors
         */
        map<string, Segmentor*> segmentors;

        /**
                 * contain all the available Filters
         */
        map<string, Filter::Filter*> filters;

                /**
                 * Database for the optimization speaker alignment
                 */
                SpeakerMatch* m_pSpeakerMatch;

                /** the logger */
        static Logger* logger;
```

I first tried removing both the `Filter` namespace and the two colons (`::`). I had found a few sites ([1](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/class.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574143/syntax-of-declaring-a-constructor-in-header-h-and-then-defining-in-a-class-fi), [3](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/), ...), where it seems that there were no examples of namespaces and double colons in header files. They were only in implementation files. I removed `Filter::` (from the line in question and from some other lines in `recording.cpp`), but that gave me

```
In file included from main.cpp:20:0:
recording.h:122:28: error: template argument 2 is invalid
         map<string, Filter*> filters;
                            ^
recording.h:122:28: error: template argument 4 is invalid
```

After studying the double-quote operator (e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5257/bladq/index.html)), and with the help of the other solution, I changed all `Filter::Filter*` to `::Filter`.

It compiled with some warnings, <s>but the rest of the installation process worked</s>. **Let me clarify** The `make config` and `make all` parts worked. There were errors in the `make test` part, detailed in another question here (to be asked). However, running `make install` creates the executables that I need.

For information about the prepended double-colon, I got some help from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon). The two colons "stuck on" before the constructor let us know that it is in the global scope, i.e. outside of the recording.h/.cpp. This is necessary, because in `recording.h/.cpp`, there is another `Filter` method for the `Recording` object created. (Things are becoming clearer as I'm writing.)

```
$ cat src/asclite/core/recording.cpp | head -n 290 | tail -5
/**
 * Filter the references and hypothesis with the availables filters.
 */
void Recording::Filter(const vector<string> & _filters)
{

$ cat src/asclite/core/recording.h | head -n 75 | tail -4
        /**
         * Filter the references and hypothesis with the availables filters.
         */
        void Filter(const vector<string> & _filters);
```

I think that the reason we don't have a namespace (i.e. there's no `Filter` before the `::`) is explained [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22271344/6505499). In this post, code for a constructor in a .cpp (implementation) file is given with an explanation:

> ```
> Mems::Mems() //you don't actually need to use the class keyword in your .cpp file; 
> just the class name, the double colon, and the method name is enough to mark this 
> as a class method
> ```

As I understand it, putting `Filter::Filter` in the code for a `Recording` object would suggest that `Filter::Filter` is a class method for a `Recording` object, but that doesn't make sense, because the first `Filter` before the colons obviously marks it as being a class method for a `Filter` object.

**If this explanation is wrong or unclear, don't hesitate to fix it.**

**This solution fixed the issue in the question, but there was [more to do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283077/6505499) before the checks for the install succeeded.**